# What type of ebike motor would work best for a 13” tire?

Tags: electric-bike, battery

I want to drive a yard cart with a motor / battery.  The cart has 13” wheels and weighs ~200 pounds loaded.  I want to walk behind it, so I’ll need to be able to control the speed between 1-3 mph.

After looking at different options, I think using an ebike motor is easiest solution. Is there an ebike motor that I could couple with 1:1 ratio and have enough torque?

Ideally, the motor / gearing would freewheel to still allow manual operation.  The more 'rainproof' the solution is, the better...

So far: adapting a freewheel to my wheel hub(s) is the best solution I have.  If I use a 20T BMX style freewheel and a geared motor with a 9T gear, max speed would be ~9 MPH, but I'm thinking I will be controllable...

Comment: So there's no bicycle here?   You probably be better off asking on DIY.se or maybe lifehacks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about bicycles

Comment: cannot see a scenario where this works out cheaper than a pre-built electric cart

Comment: @ojs This question is about the use of bicycle parts.  Maybe they won't be used exactly how you want...

Comment: @Affe For the purposes of this question the object is a 'cart', but it isn't something you can just buy.

Comment: Any standard off the shelf internally geared in-hub eBike motor like the ubiquitous 500W Bafang has plenty of torque to get 200lbs moving and you could lace it into 12" children's BMX wheel.  A non-pedelec mid drive that could do it at 1:1 would be an uncommon part to find.

Comment: You may also find it difficult to go that *slow* using an off the shelf eBike kit.

Comment: @Affe All these kits have a throttle, so presumably I could just keep the throttle position as 'slow' (or ~10%).  Do any of these motors or kits have a power vs. speed curve? (just to know if it is going to develop enough starting power)

Comment: _"For the purposes of this question the object is a 'cart', but it isn't something you can just buy"_ -- your question doesn't belong here anyway, but...what do you mean, _"it isn't something you can just buy"?_ There are lots of options for electric powered yard carts. E.g. https://www.overlandcarts.com/electric-garden-carts/ When you post this question in an appropriate forum, you'd better explain in what way _"it isn't something you can just buy"_ because based on the information you've provided so far, it definitely _is_ something _"you can just buy"_.

Comment: In my experience the 'lightest' throttle engagement you can achieve with an off the shelf kit and the controller/ coarse thumb throttle will push a 200lbs bike+rider more like 10mph than 1-3 mph.  Perhaps the controller could go slower if you fit a less coarse throttle but now we're basically ventured into electronics SE :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho  I asked the question in this forum because I want to try and use bike parts. In my mind a bicycle question forum is the best place to find someone knowledgeable on the technical abilities of bicycle parts.

Comment: @shaun5 Are you stuck on a hub motor?  a mid drive motor would give you gearing options, but would need either an IGH or a derailleur.    Also, do you want to drive one wheel or two or three or four wheels (guessing its got at least 3 wheels) ?  Does the design have a single driveshaft between two wheels (ie, like a trailer)

Comment: @Criggie I'm open to just about anything I can make work.  Ideally, I will still be able to push the cart manually.  The cart currently has 4 wheels on separate bearings (so turning one wheel doesn't turn the other side).  The number of wheels can changed.  I was thinking to drive only one wheel, but if that results in something that only wants to turn, I can drive two or change to 3 wheels and drive the center one...

Comment: Would a golf cart work? Maybe you can find one used in your area. It wouldn’t be horrifically hard to wire up a remote control for the throttle.

Comment: @MaplePanda If you mean use a golf cart instead of 'my cart', no.  I actually own a golf cart.  The parts are relatively big and heavy (especially the batteries) and they physically won't fit on my cart. If I was going to salvage parts, I think the best option would be from a mobility chair, but I'd prefer to come up with a bike part solution...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about a bicycle, human powered vehicle, or a bicycle powered by an electric/combustion engine. Questions about using bicycle parts outside their design scope are outside of our experience and will generate opinion answers.

Answer (score 2):

Good afternoon,

Whilst I appreciate you prefer to use bicycle parts, you may find it beneficial to search for scooter or wheelbarrow hub motor/wheel. The benefits of which would be - they're water tight, they're simple (a nut to hold the axle at either side is all you need to secure it) and they have lots of tread.

You can also run it using a motor controller which has a "walk assist mode" - this will disable the throttle and lock/limit the speed to around 6km/h, alternatively as previously discussed - physically impede a thumb throttle to limit input.

A 36v "hoverboard" battery would be fine (and small), all the torque is at the bottom end of these motors so that's not something you should worry about.

If you're looking to run more than one motor simultaneously - that's not something I have ever successfully accomplished, it is possible you can just disassemble a hoverboard - use  the footplate pressure sensors to turn the motor controller on when you grab the handles, the gyroscopes as the throttle - so the cart accelerates when you lift the handle(s), each of the wheels to drive one side of the cart.

** In fact, don't do any of that, I think just invented something!

All of these things exist, regrettably I am unsure of the rules in relation to posting links but if you're still looking, let me know.

[image: You can even put a sweet rotor on it]